# CSS centering gives different results

Tags: css, webkit, center

Consider this code to center a div relative to it's parent element:

```
div {
width:200px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-110px;
padding:10px;
display:table;
}
```

We are using (width/2) - padding, right?

Why is it that all Webkit based browsers (Safari and Chrome) center this div 10px to much to the left? This 10px is the padding.

**So we have two fronts here:**

1. *Chrome + Safari* -> padding must no be **included** to center correctly
2. *Firefox, IE, Opera* -> padding must **not** be **included** to center correctly

Now my question is, which one of both is actually doing it right?

EDIT:

Apperantly; the problem only occurs when adding display:table; to the div. Made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rhKW7/1/[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKW7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to recreate your issue. Your code works across browsers.

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SXzbF/1/

***Edit:*** I figured out what the issue is:

In Chrome (at least), if you set `display:table`, then as a result the padding of that element is not used. I guess, that's because, for TABLE elements, padding is only set to TD element (to the cells), and not to the TABLE element. I am not sure if setting padding on TABLE is valid, but I recommend you to not do it, but instead set the padding on the cells.

Comment: I'm sorry. I guess I've simplified the problem a bit to much. I will update the code in a moment.

Comment: Found the problem: This problem only occurs when adding display:table; to the child element.

Comment: @DADU Yes, tables screw up stuff. I knew that already :) Why are you using `display:table` on a DIV instead of using the TABLE element directly?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - That's a very good question. Every child element of an anchor element has underlining too. Now my child element is a span element. The only way I've found to remove that underlining on the span inside the anchor in Webkit, is to set it's display property to table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Superb answer that solved the problem and clarified things.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You should use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That will center the element in its parent.

Comment: Golez But the DIV is absolutely positioned. I don't think that works in such cases.

Comment: This is a fine technique but doesn't work with absolute positioned elements.

Comment: I assumed the positioning is part of your attempt to center the element. If that is not the case, this is unfortunately not a valid solution. But why center an absolute positioned element? Centering seems to imply relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation you could contain the element that needs to be centered in a div that is 100% width and absolutely positioned and then with the current element that you have use the margin:0 auto to center it within the absolutely positioned element.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible this time because there can't be any extra elements added.